# Structuring Salt State Files for Staged Environments

Tags: saltstack

How should Salt State Files and Pillar configurations be structured to enable smooth deployment of varying minion roles for staged environments like *dev*, *qa* and *production* as well as feature branches?

I have arranged my root and pillar state files as follows in a separate repository from my Python project's source code:

```
salt-states/
    pillar/
        web/
            init.sls
            production.sls
            qa.sls
            dev.sls
        db/
            init.sls
            production.sls
            qa.sls
            dev.sls
        top.sls
    roots/
        web/
            init.sls
            production.sls
            qa.sls
            dev.sls
        db/
            init.sls
            production.sls
            qa.sls
            dev.sls
    top.sls
```

How should my top.sls file look to take advantage of this structure and how can I target feature branches in this fashion?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using gitfs and git_pillar.

Gitfs allows you to keep your file_roots in a git repo. Your master branch becomes your "base" environment and each branch and tag become environments as well.

http://docs.saltstack.com/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html?highlight=gitfs

Git_pillar is similar.

http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/pillar/all/salt.pillar.git_pillar.html